# What is the meaning of the parameter coif1 in wavelet decomposition?

Tags: matlab, wavelet-transform

I have code for wavelet transform. Here they are using `coif1` to decompose the signal. Can anybody explain what is the use of `coif1`? and what does it mean?

This is the code:

```
function wavelet = waveletTransform(image)
% input: image to process and extract wavelet coefficients from
% output: 1x20 feature vector containing the first 2 moments of wavelet
% coefficients

imgGray = double(rgb2gray(image))/255;
imgGray = imresize(imgGray, [256 256]);

coeff_1 = dwt2(imgGray', 'coif1');
coeff_2 = dwt2(coeff_1, 'coif1');
coeff_3 = dwt2(coeff_2, 'coif1');
coeff_4 = dwt2(coeff_3, 'coif1');

% construct the feaute vector
meanCoeff = mean(coeff_4);
stdCoeff = std(coeff_4);

wavelet = [meanCoeff stdCoeff];

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the Matlab documentation [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ref/dwt2.html?searchHighlight=dwt2) and [there](https://www.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ref/wfilters.html) (documentation for the parameter `wname`), you will see that it means that the wavelet `coif1` is the type of the wavelet, which is in this case from the coiflet family.

It is the wavelet used as filter for the decomposition of the image.

Comment: Can you tell me ,why it is decomposing the image up to 4 parts?

Comment: This is the definition of the wavelet-transform. I suggest you to read the related wikipedia article to get started: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_wavelet_transform and maybe some tutorials about it. This is off-topic here as it is absolutely not related to programming.